# Regular Expression AST with forest or qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees, tikz-qtree, qtree, forest

I would like to represent an abstract syntax tree over a regular expression. Preferable in the form of the following tree:

```
                            <regexp>
                               |
                               |
                               |
                  (seq <regexp> <regexp>)
                         /          \
                        /            \
                       /              \
(seq <regexp> <regexp>)                (seq <regexp> <regexp>)
        |        |                             |        |
        |        |                             |        |
        |        |                             |        |
    (atom 1)  (atom 2)                     (atom 3)  (atom 4)
```

I have looked at both `tikz-qtree` and `forest`, but while the last package looks very powerful I'm not quite sure how I'd make it do what I want.

Any tips or ideas on how tackle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option (I wasn't sure about the exact placement for the edges from the root to the level 1 nodes, so I followed the diagram in the question as closed as possible):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  before typesetting nodes={content=\texttt{#1}}
}  
[<regexp>,s sep=0pt
  [(seq,edge={draw=none}]
  [<regexp>,edge={draw=none}
    [(atom 1)]
  ]
  [<regexp>)
    [(atom 2)]
  ]
  [(seq]
  [<regexp>,edge={draw=none}
    [(atom 3)]
  ]
  [<regexp>),edge={draw=none}
    [(atom 4)]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The lines

```
for tree={
  before typesetting nodes={content=\texttt{#1}}
}
```

simply typeset the labels in mono-spaced fonts; delete them if not required.